# Error Exception java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java

I am trying to remove items from my list while iterate, that is why he used Iterator, to later insert emails into a queue. But I get the following error when inserting more elements:

```
Iterator<String> listCorreos = request.getCorreos().iterator();

            while (listCorreos.hasNext()) {
                for (Cola cola : colas) {
                    String correo = listCorreos.next();
                    cola.insertar(correo);
                    System.err.println("Se agrego " + correo + " a la cola: " + cola.obtenerNombre());
                        listCorreos.remove();
                }
            }
```

I get the following error

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
```

Thank you in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: You are calling `#next` on your Iterator in a loop, while only checking `#hasNext` one time per entire loop. It looks like you're trying to almost double-iterate, but overall you can pull `String correo = listCorreos.next();` outside of the `for` loop.

Comment: Hi Maria! I don't fully understand your code, but I think you have to move the while loop inside the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have two loops and in the second loop you are getting the next element from the object controlling loop 1

See line `String correo = listCorreos.next();`

```
        while (listCorreos.hasNext()) { // loop 1
            for (Cola cola : colas) { // loop 2
                String correo = listCorreos.next(); // Here is your problem. the number of colas and the number of items in listCorreos are apparently matched up
                cola.insertar(correo);
                System.err.println("Se agrego " + correo + " a la cola: " + cola.obtenerNombre());
                    listCorreos.remove();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to do.

But

```
    Iterator<String> listCorreos = request.getCorreos().iterator();

    while (listCorreos.hasNext()) {
        String correo = listCorreos.next(); //Notice Moved Line!
        for (Cola cola : colas) {                    
            cola.insertar(correo);
            System.err.println("Se agrego " + correo + " a la cola: " + cola.obtenerNombre());
            
        }
        listCorreos.remove();//Also moved.
     }
```

Is probably closer to what you want.
Certainly `hasNext()` is only "good" for one call to `next()`.
Similarly you can only remove the current item of an iterator once.

But if `colas` has more than one element you're breaking those constraints.